# Is it possible to say ' your choice *for* something' when you mean 'your choice *of* something'?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I'm correcting a document and several people that co-wrote it seem to agree that 'my choice for' seems to be synonymous to 'my choice of', in the signification of me having chosen something and indicating what exactly my choice was. E.g. 'my choice for Japan as my travel destination'.

To me this seems wrong, a choice 'for' should be used to indicate a reason or goal, or a person that will be affected by the decision in my experience with English ('I chose a book for English class' - 'my choice for my daughter's education is school X'). Is this true or is saying 'my choice for chicken as dinner' correct English?

Comment: What is your choice for dinner tonight? Do you view dinner as a goal?

Comment: 'for dinner' seems to me a rather idiomatic expression. Could you say 'What is your choice for favourite football team?'

Comment: @Waldo In the US we'd just say "What's your favourite football team?" Of course we're talking about a different football. :)

Comment: I think you may be onto something, but it's hard to say for sure when we don't get to see the rest of the sentence in your example. _'A long-held desire to see where my grandparents lived was behind my choice for Japan as my travel destination'_ sounds acceptable to me.

Answer (score 5):

OP is mixing up two different constructions...

> *My choice **of** [one out of several possible options].*
> e.g - *My choice **of chicken** for dinner was made on health grounds.*
>
> *My choice **for** [some particular role which your choice fulfils]*.
> e.g. - *My choice **for dinner** was chicken, because it's healthier than red meat*.

I can't say exactly why OP's *'choice [of] chicken **as** dinner'* is wrong. In that exact construction, *"as"* doesn't sound at all good to me. But if, say, an American was talking about how he'd voted, *"My choice of Romney **as** president turned out to be a minority opinion"* sounds reasonable. Perhaps that's just because I conflate it with *"My **vote for Romney as** president..."*.

Comment: Correct. You might note, however, that under these constraints OP's  'my choice for Japan as my travel destination' is wrong - it should be my choice **of** Japan for my destination. ... *As dinner* is wrong because one **has** chicken *(for dinner**. But one might be unsure whether to employ it *as dinner* rather than, say, *as a featherduster* or *as a football*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Suppose the cook had chicken *and* fish, and needed to choose which to use for/as dinner, and which as supper? Could she not say *"My choice of fish as supper was subsequently endorsed by Google Books - [fish supper](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fish+supper%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):9320, [chicken supper](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22chicken+supper%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):6090"*. Sounds plausible to me.

Comment: Well, GB has 227 hits on "choose for supper" and Zero on "choose as supper". I'd dock her pay on stylistic grounds, and fire her for being so insecure in her own professional judgment that she'd refer the question to GB.

Comment: @StoneyB: Dang! You is a hard taskmaster, Boss! She only the *cook* - she ain't got no schooling in reading an' writing an' such! Anyway, although Google Internet has 4900 hits for *"choice of romney **for** president"*, and only 2 for *"choice of romney **as** president"*, does that make the second version "wrong"? Or just "much less common"?

Comment: "X as president" doesn't bother me, though I personally would not "vote for X as president" because to my ear that's too close to implying either **that I** am president or that X already is.

Comment: @StoneyB: I rest my case. It's easier to choose someone *as* president than to choose something *as* dinner, but we have no clear rationale for this. Though it does seem to me it's tied up with the fact that being president is a "role" anyone could take on (in the land of the free), whereas being dinner is just what dinner does.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, these two phrases mean different things.

Compare these:

**My choice of chicken for dinner** [was a good one].

**My choice for dinner was chicken.**

*My choice of* (one of two or more things) ie, chicken as opposed to anything else on the menu.

*My choice for* (a separate object not connected to the things avaible for your choice)

The separate object could be a reason (I chose this car **for the simple fact** that it's the best there is) or an object/person (I chose this car **for you** because it's the best there is).

I think this is best shown by the fact that *My choice for* is not a phrase that is often heard, it sounds more like an announcement. It is best reworded as *I chose ... for*.